# Why does an asmx file have to have a webservice with just an int as a parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, .net-4.0, asmx

I have an asmx web service which requires a string and two ints to return data.  When I run the asmx page directly and invoke it, I get a 500 error and on chrome get the following:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerType..ctor(Type type)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

But, when I add the following web service to the asmx.cs file along side my actual web service, it works.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public string getBlah(int blah)
{
    return "blah";
}
```

I then went to a few older sites I've worked on, all of which had at least one web service that just had an int for input, and when I removed the int only web service, the rest failed.  So why does asmx web services require a web service with only an int as a parameter for the other web services to work?

This is happening on .Net 4.  Haven't tested any other versions.

EDIT:

I was able to create a mockup that is broken, but even adding the int doesn't seem to fix this one.  I created a new web forms .net 4 project and added the following asmx file to it.  Commenting out AMethod causes Owners to break instead of returning nothing.  I'm using values a, 1, 1 for the three fields of the Owner webservice.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;


namespace WebApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://www.mysite.com/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
        public string AMethod(int page)
        {
            return "blah";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
        public void Owners(string searchTerm, int pageSize, int page)
        {
            string retJson = "";

            Context.Response.Write(retJson);
        }

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
        public string Results(List<string> counties, List<string> field2, List<string> field3, string owners, int pageSize, int page)
        {
            return "[\"test\":\"hi\",\"test2\":\"bye\"]";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: ASMX web services have no such restriction. There's clearly something wrong with your code. Please post the code and let us see what's wrong with it.

Comment: I'll try to mock up a new one that demonstrates this and post the code.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I've added code that reproduces the error for me.

Comment: What URL as you using that causes the code to break? Also, please post the full exception that you receive.

Comment: I'm running the webservice locally.  So I have http://localhost:50413/WebService1.asmx as the url.  I then click on Owners and the url is http://localhost:50413/WebService1.asmx?op=Owners.

Comment: The error generated in IE is a standard 'The website cannot display the page' with more information saying it is a 500 error.  When I use chrome, I get the error message I already posted at the top (that is the entirety of the message).

Comment: No, what is the URL you use to pass parameters to the service?

Comment: I'm invoking it by running it directly on my local machine.  There is no other URL involved.  Here is a gif (that I just found online) that shows how it looks (except I get the error after clicking on the Invoke button).  `http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-4ipTYkNGUPg/UmtT4pfSU7I/AAAAAAAAFWs/tYS1vif0BmI/s1600/FinalWebservice.Gif`

Comment: _How_ are you calling the service? Did you use "Add Service Reference", or "Add Web Reference"? Please show the code you  use to call the service.

Comment: I'm calling the code through the invoke GUI that is autogenerated when you run an asmx file.  That shows it working and not working in the cases I've described.

Comment: And, what is the URL generated by the invoke GUI, the URL that fails?

Answer (score 0):

500 is Internal server error it indicates about ur logic error.
This will help u to understand how to work with WebService.asmx.

### .aspx side

fetching input by scripting.

```
        function InsertDetail() {
        var prhid = $("#<%=PRHId.ClientID%>").val();
        var item = $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").val();
        var Quantity = $("#<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>").val();
        var Price = $("#<%=TextBox3.ClientID%>").val();
        var Make = $("#<%=TextBox4.ClientID%>").val();
        var Discription = $("#<%=TextBox5.ClientID%>").val();
        var d = [];

      
        d.push(prhid);
        d.push(item);
        d.push(Quantity);
        d.push(Price);
        d.push(Make);
        d.push(Discription);
        var jsnDta = JSON.stringify({ d: d });
        alert(jsnDta);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "InsertRequestDetail.asmx/InsertDetail",
            data: jsnDta,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {


                var rtnData = r.d; //all returned data...
                var respDta = [];
                $.map(rtnData, function (item, index) {
                    var j = [
                        item.status,
                        item.msg,

                    ];
                    respDta.push(j);

                });





                $.each(respDta, function (key, value) {
                    var status = value[0];
                    var msg = value[1];


                    if (status == true) {

                        alert(msg);


                    } else {
                        alert("Error" + msg);
                    }




                });
```

### .asmx side

now all we need to do is call values of fetched inputs and save it in Db table.

```
 public class InsertRequestDetail : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    [WebMethod]
    public List<RequestResponse> InsertDetail(List<string> d)
    {
        List<RequestResponse> list = new List<RequestResponse>();

        string prhid = d[0];
        string item = d[1];
        string Quantity = d[2];
        string Price = d[3];
        string Make = d[4];
        string Discription = d[5];

        Pro_DbCon obj2 = new Pro_DbCon();
        string constr = obj2.dbconnection();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string select = "Select * From Pro_Detail where PRHId = @prhid AND Item = @item AND Quantity = @quantity AND Price = @price AND Make = @make AND Discription = @dis";
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(select, con);

            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prhid", prhid);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", item);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", Quantity);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Price);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@make", Make);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dis", Discription);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {

                dr.Close();
                RequestResponse r = new RequestResponse();
                r.status = false;
                r.msg = "Duplicate";
                list.Add(r);
            }
            else
            {
                dr.Close();
                string insertquery = "Insert into Pro_Detail (PRHId,Item,Quantity,Price,Make,Discription ) values (@prhid,@item,@quantity,@price,@make,@dis)";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertquery, con);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prhid", prhid);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", item);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", Quantity);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Price);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@make", Make);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dis", Discription);
                int affectedrows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (affectedrows > 0)
                {
                    RequestResponse r = new RequestResponse();
                    r.status = true;
                    r.msg = "success";
                    list.Add(r);
                }
                else
                {
                    RequestResponse r = new RequestResponse();
                    r.status = false;
                    r.msg = "error on adding";
                    list.Add(r);
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            RequestResponse r = new RequestResponse();
            r.status = false;
            r.msg = "Error !" + ex.ToString();
            list.Add(r);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        

        return list;
    }
}
```

In case u get 500 internal Server error Related .asmx is the place to look for logic errors or mistyping.